# Convert hex to decimal in R

Tags: r, hex, decimal

I found out that there is function called `.hex.to.dec` in the `fBasics` package.

When I do `.hex.to.dec(a)`, it works.

I have a data frame with a column `samp_column` consisting of such values:

```
a373, 115c6, a373, 115c6, 176b3
```

When I do `.hex.to.dec(samp_column)`, I get this error:

> "Error in nchar(b) : 'nchar()' requires a character vector"

When I do `.hex.to.dec(as.character(samp_column))`, I get this error:

> "Error in rep(base.out, 1 + ceiling(log(max(number), base =
>   base.out))) : invalid 'times' argument"

What would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: `strtoi` will do it.  Or the long way: `Rutils::as.character.binmode`  and then convert from character to number with `as.numeric` :-)

Comment: Please read about [how to format your question](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and then about [how to make a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that includes your data.

Comment: Thank you Carl! For some reason, this function did not show up in my Google searches, but it seems to work really well. :) Cheers!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use `base::strtoi` to convert hexadecimal character vectors to integer:

```
strtoi(c("0xff", "077", "123"))
#[1] 255  63 123
```

Comment: Conversion across numeric bases is one of those tasks where it can be difficult to locate the right help pages. The conversion functions are scattered all over the place with diverse names. See also `?hexmode`, `?as.hexmode`, and `?octmode`

Comment: OK, *now* who's posting short answers? :-).  PS thx for the pinball praise .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft ha! Ok, point taken. I prefer to think of this as a minimum workable example, but as you said, it's a fine line pinball wizard. :-)

Comment: For some reason, when I try to follow your example and try `strtoi(c('a','b','c','d','e','f'))`, all I get is NA. But your examples work just fine. What am I missing here? EDIT: OK, I needed to add `0x` before each hex number.

Comment: @dasf you need to specify the base `strtoi(c('a','b','c','d','e','f'), 16)` should return an answer

Answer (score 15):

There is a simple and generic way to convert hex <-> other formats using "C/C++ way":

```
V <- c(0xa373, 0x115c6, 0xa373, 0x115c6, 0x176b3)

sprintf("%d", V)
#[1] "41843" "71110" "41843" "71110" "95923"

sprintf("%.2f", V)
#[1] "41843.00" "71110.00" "41843.00" "71110.00" "95923.00"

sprintf("%x", V)
#[1] "a373"  "115c6" "a373"  "115c6" "176b3"
```

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned in [@user4221472's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45971461/4341436), `strtoi()` overflows with integers larger than 2^31.

The simplest way around that is to use `as.numeric()`.

```
V <- c(0xa373, 0x115c6, 0x176b3, 0x25cf40000)

as.numeric(V)
#[1]       41843       71110       95923 10149429248
```

As @MS Berends noted in the comments, "[a]lso notice that just printing `V` in the console will already print in decimal."

Comment: Nice... You might add, that you can set `options(digits = 22)` if one does not like scientific notation.

Comment: Just commenting to remark this has been extremely useful to bypass the mentioned limitation of 31 bits in `strtoi`

Comment: Also notice that just printing `V` in the console will already print in decimal.

Answer (score 8):

`strtoi()` has a limitation of 31 bits. Hex numbers with the high order bit set return `NA`:

```
> strtoi('0x7f8cff8b')
[1] 2139946891
> strtoi('0x8f8cff8b')
[1] NA
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a signed value with 16 bits:

```
  temp <- strtoi(value, base=16L)
  if (temp>32767){ temp <- -(65535 - temp) }
```

In a general form:

```
  max_unsigned <- 65535 #0xFFFF
  max_signed <- 32767 #0x7FFF
  temp <- strtoi(value, base=16L)
  if (temp>max_signed){ temp <- -(max_unsigned- temp) }
```